# Invalid field/related field combination

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm trying to make an entity like vendor in ax 2012. When I click the "new" button I get following error;

> Invalid field/related field combination.

I have looked for it on search engines and found out that it might be due to wrong joins used in data sources of the form. I have gone through the joins and links, they all are fine but I'm still getting the same error.

Any one, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in the `info.add` method to catch AX in the deed.

Comment: umm... will you please elaborate info.add method. Where is this method present?

Comment: In the `info` class, hence `info.add`.