# How to locate the method using an error message string?

Tags: axapta

I would like to know where is this error code located in the AOT. Would like to know the path to understand the structure and develop custom code.

[image]

> Transaction has been selected, for settlement, although settlement type: none was selected

Comment: Add breakpoint to `add` method of class `Info` and check callstack

Comment: You may be able to click the `Edit` button in your image too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use one of two methods to locate message strings.

1. Provided the [cross reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-create-the-cross-reference-system) is updated (it should be in dev) use the "Label editor" to to search for then string, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882964/4509).
2. Put a breakpoint in top of `info.add` method, disable CIL if needed, then rerun to get the error message invoking the debugger, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16812346/4509).